# Css vertically align to browsers height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image and a div i would like to align them both vertically on the browser like in the image attached. with both in the middle of the browser and the div in the middle of the image 
whats the best was to do this with css or javascript
[image]

Comment: http://demosthenes.info/blog/723/Seven-Ways-of-Centering-With-CSS

Comment: depends a lot on the surrounding parent nodes and whether or not they are relatively or absolutely positioned. in most cases a div within a div can be centered via margin auto, assuming it has height and width defined. you would do better to provide an html + css example with something like jsfiddle for these types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the width and height of the box you're trying to move you can use the following:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; /*your width*/
    height: 300px; /*your height*/
    top: 50%; /*offset top 50% of screen height*/
    left: 50%; /*same as top*/
    margin-left: -150px; /*subtract half of the width to 'center' horizontally*/
    margin-top: -150px /*same as left but for vertical centering*/
}
```

a box without the negative margins would have their top border on the 50% height line, this is not what you want and that is why you subtract half the height and width from the box, to nullify those differences.

ofcourse this is a random 300px width box, you need to see the width and heights for yourself in the code you have to write. the negative margins are always half of their original respective width or height.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using  the resource from 
[demosthenes.info/blog/723/Seven-Ways-of-Centering-With-CSS](http://www.demosthenes.info/blog/723/Seven-Ways-of-Centering-With-CSS) 
recommend by Parfait